# microservice architectural choice using api gateway with web portal application

Tags: spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-zuul

I'm currently working on a microservices architecture. Thoses microservices will be integrated in web-portal which will be the entry point. I'd need to use an api gateway(edge-server) but i'm wondering if it's better to create a separate microservice dedicated to api gateway or use the web-portal microservice as api gateway.

What do you think would be a better choice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An api gateway should be the only way your miroservices should be accessed. 
So the microservices should use each other through the api service as well. 
I would not like my microservices to call the webportal as an api service.

Another point is, that you can't scale the api service (**which is a bottle neck by design**) independet of the ui.

**So my suggestion is**: Create the api gateway as a separate microservice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yannic for your pertinent analysis. I'm implementing also SSO with Oauth2. How would then handle single logout from webportal in this architecture?

Comment: Need more information about your architecture. A diagram would help